# Firefox — How to preserve history?

Tags: firefox, history

Is there an option in Firefox which "archives" expired history rather than erasing it? For example if it could save expired URLs to a file that would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there an option in Firefox which "archives" expired history rather than erasing it?

I'm not aware of one.

However you could use [BrowsingHistoryView - View browsing history of your Web browsers](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/browsing_history_view.html) at regular intervals to export your history to csv/tab-delimited/html/xml.

This can be done from the command line, so a scheduled task could be written to save it in the background every month or so.

> BrowsingHistoryView is a utility that reads the history data of different Web browsers (Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, Microsoft Edge, Opera) and displays the browsing history of all these Web browsers in one table. The browsing history table includes the following information: Visited URL, Title, Visit Time, Visit Count, Web browser and User Profile. BrowsingHistoryView allows you to watch the browsing history of all user profiles in a running system, as well as to get the browsing history from external hard drive.
>
> **You can also export the browsing history into csv/tab-delimited/html/xml** file from the user interface, or **from command-line, without displaying any user interface**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source [BrowsingHistoryView - View browsing history of your Web browsers](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/browsing_history_view.html)

<sup>Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with [Nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.</sup>